# Loading control A (\u0001) delimited file to Google Big Query

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Any pointer on how to load CSV file which has Ctrl A (\u0001) character as delimiter to BQ table? I want to load it from BQ CLI and it supports only single character.

Comment: Please add more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try specifying a delimiter with the flag [`--field_delimiter`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#loading_csv_data_into_a_table) added to the `bq load` command. More precisely `--field_delimiter=$(printf '\u0001')`.

Comment: Thanks it worked. Also I tried giving control A (i.e. cntrl+V+A) directly and that too also worked for me. i.e. -F'^A'